# Shell script unknown operand alpine

Tags: docker, sh

I am running into a problem where my shell script doesn't work if the variable is not set/set to empty string.

For this I am using the `alpine` image

```
docker run -dt alpine
docker exec -it <container> sh
```

Here is the problematic code:

```
x=""
sh -c "if [ "$x" != "required" ]; then sed; fi"
```

When `x` is not set, I get the error:

```
sh: required: unknown operand
```

This seems to only be the problem on an empty string. If I set `x="lkajsdfasl"`, it will work just fine.

This just breaks down on an empty string/not set.

Due to the way my `docker-compose` is setup, I can only use `sh` and have to use `sh -c`

Comment: I suspect this is a quoting issue - if that variable is not set, the first round of quoting changes the expression to `if [  != required ]; then sed; fi`. You can change `sh -c` to `echo` to investigate this possibility.

Comment: Hmm. In this case, it is printing `if [ redf != required ]; then sed; fi`

Comment: Nevermind Idk why redf showed up, its printing exactly what you have above

Comment: That can happen if you edit a shell script while it's running. Otherwise I have no idea.

Comment: Yeah once I recreate the docker image it seems to have fixed itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a quoting issue. Use single quotes around the command like this

```
sh -c 'if [ "$x" != "required" ]; then sed; fi'
```